# Y a-t-il un équivalent français de l'expression « team retreat »?

Tags: traduction, anglais, société

L'expression « team retreat » en anglais est utilisée pour désigner quelques jours que des collègues de bureau passent ensemble, a priori pour resserrer les rangs, au cours desquels ils vont travailler une partie de la journée (le matin et le soir) et pratiquer une activité sportive ensemble (du ski l'après-midi par exemple). Ce n'est pas juste une retraite, c'est aussi un élément de management utilisé par le chef d'équipe.

Y a-t-il un équivalent français de l'expression « team retreat », qui véhiculerait ces deux sens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les termes les plus courants dans ces contextes sont "un **séminaire**" ou "une **convention**".

---

S'agissant d'une expression *corporate*, elle est reprise telle quelle dans certaines firmes.
Espérons qu'il ne soit pas trop tard pour trouver l'expression française qui corresponde le mieux.

Answer (score 4):

Le mot "retraite" est également utilisé, mais a souvent une connotation religieuse, ou au moins spirituelle. Dans le milieu associatif étudiant, il y a une sorte d'équivalent, les week-ends d'intégration et de formation, où une partie du temps est dévolue à la formations des nouveaux arrivants (souvent sur le fonctionnement de l'université, des différentes associations, un peu d'historique), et le reste à la cohésion.